# Sum of First Squared n Numbers Javascript

Tags: javascript, formula

Alright so I need to make a javascript program that finds the sum of of the first squared n numbers (hence the title). I've finished almost everything except the formula

```
<hmtl>
<body>
<center>
<p1>Sum of First n Whole Numbers</p>
<p1>Please enter a value into both boxes<br>
Press the button and the computer will determine the sum of all the numbers leading up         to yours</p>
<script>
function sum() {
a = parseFloat(document.getElementById('boxone').value);


alert("The sum is "+); 
}
</script>

Value 1: <input type="text" id="boxone" value="0">
<input type="submit" onclick="sum()" value="Summarize">
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I know that the formula is `k^2=(n(n+1)(2n+1))/6`   but I have no idea how to put it in code

Comment: Smells like homework. What have you tried?

Comment: It's just simple arithmetic, didn't they teach you how to write that in your class?

Comment: put the script at the end just before the `</body>` and just replace your `a` for an `n` and all you need is to replace `k^2=` with  `Math.sqrt` and put it after the `+`... got it?

Comment: I'm distance learning the whole semester, and the only problem I'm having is with the n(n+1). the code just stops when I put that in.

Comment: You need `n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/6`. In general, you always need to be explicit about the multiplication symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alert("The sum is "+ a*(a+1)*(2*a+1)/6);
```

There is no such thing as "implicit multiplication" in any programming language (other than some symbolic math programs).  But implicit multiplication is exactly what your formula had. Also note that you need to replace the `n` with `a` since that is the variable in which you have the value of `boxone` (which I presume is the input).

It would be an interesting exercise for you to compute the value explicitly - so rather than applying the clever formula, make the computer work a little bit harder. This might be done like so:

```
var mySum = 0;
for (var i=1; i<=a; i++) {
  mySum = mySum + a * a;
}

alert("the long way, I get " + mySum);
```

Comment: hmm everything seems to work fine(thanks for that), but it looks like I've got the formula all wrong. Any chance you, or for that matter anyone know it?

Comment: I just spotted a typo in my first expression - when I changed `n` to `a`, I accidentally overwrote the `2`. See if that fixes it. You have the right formula - see http://www.fredonia.edu/faculty/math/JonathanCox/math/SumOfSquares/SumOfSquares.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to rewrite it by taking the square roots of both sides:

`k=Math.sqrt((n*(n+1)*(2*n+1))/6);`

If `n` is always positive, you can discard the negative root as the sum will always be positive.

Comment: Since this is the sum from 1 to n, I think that n is always positive... And you need `2*n` not `2n`.

Comment: Thanks, missed the * in my copy and paste.